# Making a Rock, Paper, Scissors game in Python. Just curious on how to make multiple rounds in it

Tags: python

I've asked the user to input how many rounds they want to play, but I don't actually know how to make the program play for another round. near the end of the code I'm trying to make the score add up to the rounds as well. Any help?

```
import time
import random
print ("Welcome to the Rock, Paper, Scissors Game!")
time.sleep(1)
rounds = int(raw_input("How many rounds would you like to play?"))
while rounds not in range(3,11):
    try:
        rounds = int(raw_input("Sorry! I can only play between 3 and 10 rounds. Try again:"))
    except:
        print ("ERROR invalid input. Out of range or wrong type of data.")
if rounds in range(3,11):
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Challenge accepted! I will play you for", rounds,"rounds! Let's begin!!!")
options = ("rock","paper","scissors")
userChoice = raw_input("Rock, Paper or Scissors, peasant?")
while userChoice not in options:
    try:
        userChoice = raw_input("Not an option lad. Rock, paper or scissors")
    except:
        print ("ERROR invalid input. Out of range or wrong type of data.")
cpuoption1 = "rock"
cpuoption2 = "paper"
cpuoption3 = "scissors"
cpuChoice = random.randint(1,3)
answer = ""
if cpuChoice == 1:
    answer = cpuoption1
elif cpuChoice == 2:
    answer = cpuoption2
elif cpuChoice == 3:
    answer = cpuoption3
print ("I choose", answer,"!")
user= 0 
cpu = 0
if userChoice == "rock" and answer == cpuoption1:
    user += 1
    cpu += 1
    print ("Draw!")
elif userChoice == "paper" and answer == cpuoption2:
    user+=1
    cpu+=1
    print("Draw!")
elif userChoice == "scissors" and answer == cpuoption3:
    user+=1
    cpu+=1
    print ("Draw!")
elif userChoice == "rock" and answer == cpuoption2:
    cpu+=1
    print ("CPU wins the round!")
elif userChoice == "rock" and answer == cpuoption3:
    user+=1
    print ("Player wins the round!")
elif userChoice == "paper" and answer == cpuoption1:
    user+=1
    print ("Player wins the round!")
elif userChoice == "paper" and answer == cpuoption3:
    cpu+=1
    print ("CPU wins the round!")
elif userChoice == "scissors" and answer == cpuoption1:
    cpu+=1
    print ("CPU wins the round!")
elif userChoice == "scissors" and answer == cpuoption2:
    user+=1
    print ("Player wins the round!")
if cpu==rounds:
    print("CPU beat the player!")
elif user==rounds:
    print("Player beat the CPU!")
elif cpu==rounds and user==rounds:
    print("Looks like that was a draw! Good game!")
```

Answer (score 0):

**LOOP to play another game**

```
keep_going = True
while keep_going:
    # Here, insert all of your code to play one game

    response = raw_input("Do you want to play another game?  (Y or N)"
    keep_going = (response == 'Y')
```

I see now; you know ahead of time how many rounds you want to play?  In that case, use a **for** loop:

```
for i in range(rounds):
    # Here, insert all of your code to play one game
```

When you're done with all the games (rounds), you'll want something more like:

```
if cpu > user:
    print("CPU wins the match!")
elif user > cpu:
    print("Player wins the match!")
else:
    print("Looks like that was a draw! Good match!")
```

---

**CODING to more easily determine the winner:**

```
choice_list = { "rock":1, "paper":2, "scissors":3}
# input user choice; generate cpu choice as 1, 2, or 3
result_diff = (choice_list[userChoice] - cpuChoice) % 3
if result_diff == 0:
    print ("Draw")
elif result_diff == 1:
    print ("User wins")
    user += 1
else:
    print ("cpu wins")
    cpu += 1
```

That's the logic; I'll leave the accounting details to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a counter.

```
counter = 0
while counter <= rounds:
    #code here
    counter += 1 #when the game is over
```

Edit:

```
import time
import random
print ("Welcome to the Rock, Paper, Scissors Game!")
time.sleep(1)
rounds = int(raw_input("How many rounds would you like to play?"))
counter = 0
while counter <= rounds-1:
    while rounds not in range(3,11):
        try:
            rounds = int(raw_input("Sorry! I can only play between 3 and 10 rounds. Try again:"))
        except:
            print ("ERROR invalid input. Out of range or wrong type of data.")
    if rounds in range(3,11):
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("Challenge accepted! I will play you for", rounds,"rounds! Let's begin!!!")
    options = ("rock","paper","scissors")
    userChoice = raw_input("Rock, Paper or Scissors, peasant?")
    while userChoice not in options:
        try:
            userChoice = raw_input("Not an option lad. Rock, paper or scissors")
        except:
            print ("ERROR invalid input. Out of range or wrong type of data.")
    cpuoption1 = "rock"
    cpuoption2 = "paper"
    cpuoption3 = "scissors"
    cpuChoice = random.randint(1,3)
    answer = ""
    if cpuChoice == 1:
        answer = cpuoption1
    elif cpuChoice == 2:
        answer = cpuoption2
    elif cpuChoice == 3:
        answer = cpuoption3
    print ("I choose", answer,"!")
    user= 0
    cpu = 0
    if userChoice == "rock" and answer == cpuoption1:
        user += 1
        cpu += 1
        print ("Draw!")
        counter += 1
    elif userChoice == "paper" and answer == cpuoption2:
        user+=1
        cpu+=1
        print("Draw!")
        counter += 1
    elif userChoice == "scissors" and answer == cpuoption3:
        user+=1
        cpu+=1
        print ("Draw!")
        counter += 1
    elif userChoice == "rock" and answer == cpuoption2:
        cpu+=1
        print ("CPU wins the round!")
        counter += 1
    elif userChoice == "rock" and answer == cpuoption3:
        user+=1
        print ("Player wins the round!")
        counter += 1
    elif userChoice == "paper" and answer == cpuoption1:
        user+=1
        print ("Player wins the round!")
        counter += 1
    elif userChoice == "paper" and answer == cpuoption3:
        cpu+=1
        print ("CPU wins the round!")
        counter += 1
    elif userChoice == "scissors" and answer == cpuoption1:
        cpu+=1
        print ("CPU wins the round!")
        counter += 1
    elif userChoice == "scissors" and answer == cpuoption2:
        user+=1
        print ("Player wins the round!")
        counter += 1
    if cpu==rounds:
        print("CPU beat the player!")
    elif user==rounds:
        print("Player beat the CPU!")
        counter += 1
    elif cpu==rounds and user==rounds:
        print("Looks like that was a draw! Good game!")
        counter += 1
```